# Removing part of a file in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

Currently, I'm looking at trying to remove part of what is basically a proprietary archive format; in order to support the ability to remove a file, I'm trying to figure out how to remove a segment of the file (given an offset and a length).  I see there's plenty of append logic when it comes to the fs module of node, but nothing that seems to "splice" parts of a file.

Is this going to be even possible? Will I have to resort to the less preferred option of writing to an entirely new file instead?

Comment: What is the format?  Is the file textual or binary?  How would you know where to split?  Why wouldn't you want to write to a new file anyway?

Comment: It's SBAsset6 - format's mostly binary.  File itself has a metatable that contains a map of what amounts to a virtual filepath, an offset (in bytes), and a length (in bytes).  I'm trying to handle removal of content from the archive (either an update to a "filepath" results in a negative net change of bytes, or a file is removed) and not leave behind wasted bytes.  I'm also trying to avoid creating a new file in order to lessen the amount of I/O going on - most archives are small but I've come across some up to 250MB+.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operation System handles appending to file very quickly, there is no need to rewrite the all file when you open it for appending.

But, if you wish to slice (cut) the middle of the file, it doesn't matter which programing language do you use, you have to read the whole file and save it again.

What you can do is to create a new file, and save to it two slices of the input buffer.

```
var fs=require('fs')

var buffer=fs.readFileSync('input_file')

fs.writeFileSync("output",buffer.slice(0,20))
fs.appendFileSync("output",buffer.slice(50,100))
```